# Font Awesome en el placeholder de un input?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, icons, reactstrap

Segun vi en la documentacion, Font Awesome tiene una forma de hardcodear los iconos en un placeholder de un input, haciendo algo asi:

```
  <Input placeholder='&#xf002; Search' />
```

Esto es lo que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> No importa qué codigo ponga luego de `&#x`, siempre renderiza el mismo dibujo.

Estoy trabajando con `ReactJS`y el `Input`pertenece a la librería `Reactstrap`.
Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer reactstrap no hace nada especial sobre el atributo de placeholder, simplemente [lo redirige al tag ocupado](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/b4c45afe658ee5008274fbf687b22d35dfe12c51/src/Input.js#L130), en tu caso un input.
Yo creo que tu problema es que no estás cargando la fuente correctamente para el input:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xf002; sin font-family"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xf002; con font-family" style="font-family:Arial,FontAwesome"/>
```

Comment: exactamente esa era la solucion, el tema es que el proyecto tiene la ultima version de font awesome y no funciona en versiones > 5.x . Termine haciendo un input-group y dandole el toque con css. Gracias!